# How to get current num of google app engine instances?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-module

In case of auto scaling, how to get current num of 
google app engine instances?

Please teach me it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How calculate the number of instances in Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005701/how-calculate-the-number-of-instances-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [apps.services.versions.instances.list](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances/list) method of the [Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/) can be used to obtain the info you seek.

Comment: Thank you ... for your help.